# Question about Calculating Independent Events.

Tags: probability, statistics

If two independent events each have a $30 \%$ chance of occurring, then the chance at least one of them occurs is $51 \%$, and that neither occurs is $49 \%$. This can be solved through the equation $1 - (1-x)^2$.

I am having trouble coming up with such an equation when the two events have different probabilities of happening, say a $40 \%$ chance of $x$, and a $25 \%$ chance of $y$. While I can get to the answer by multiplying through the complimentaries ($0.6 \times 0.75 = 45 \%$ chance neither hits, so a $55 \%$ chance that at least one of them hits). I don't know of an equation to get to the answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't start your question with "hello" or other greetings since it makes it harder to search for your question. You can see more about this [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17206/saying-hello-at-the-beginning-of-a-question-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then the probability of the event of either occurring is given by:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cup B)&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B)\\[1ex]&=1-(1-\mathsf P(A))+(1-\mathsf P(A))\,\mathsf P(B)\\[1ex]&=1-(1-\mathsf P(A))\,(1-\mathsf P(B))\end{align}$$

---

So, if $\mathsf P(A)=x$ and $\mathsf P(B)=x$, then that equals $1-(1-x)^2$.

But, if $\mathsf P(A)=x$ and $\mathsf P(B)=y$, then that equals $1-(1-x)(1-y)$.

Comment: Note that $1-(1-x)(1-y)=x+y-xy$ which is an example of *inclusion-exclusion*

Comment: These are all well explained, as follow up, is there a function or equation that will solve for 'will 1 and only 1 of these eventualities happen', as opposed to 'at least 1 or more'.  I think this might be delving into binomial distribution, but not entirely sure.

And Toby, tx for the protocol assistance.

Comment: $x(1-y)+y(1-x)$ for "one but not the other."